# What are some good ways to create SWFs on the server?

Tags: flash, swf-compiler

I don't mean converting PDF or PPT to SWF, I mean more like I have data and assets and want to dynamically bust out an SWF.  Like what Generator used to do, if you ever worked with that tool.

I *know* there are tools for doing this, but when I did a search all I came up with was the idea of putting MTASC on the server.  Not that that's a bad idea, I'd just like to know what other options are there.  Or at least some suggestions for good keywords to search by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much action on this question, and I still haven't been able to find anything like what I thought I *knew* existed.

I guess there's not really a whole lot of cases where you'd need/want something like this, since you could just inject logic into a nearly empty SWF on your own.

I'm pretty sure I had a specific reason for looking for a server-side product, but I don't remember what it was.  Can't think of anything that would make dynamically compiling an SWF be very sensible, now, though.  Maybe some really specific compiler argument needs?...  Maybe?.

In that case, I guess installing a compiler on your server and building whatever tools you need to affect it would be the thing to do.  But now the whole question seems pretty silly.  :)

Comment: Have you seen http://wonderfl.net/ ? I can't find any information about how their setup works, but they have a compelling use case for server-side swf compilation.

Comment: I hadn't seen that, thanks.  Weird how little information they have on their site.  But, it's really cool to see something like that working.  If they had a reasonable API and the ability to compile entire projects, it would be a pretty interesting service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about doing it on your own server, but if you're open to using an external service, you can go with [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/). They have an API that converts stuff for you. You can see it in action on the occasional PDF link on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/).

Comment: I'm looking specifically for doing it on my own server, but this is pretty interesting.  Thanks.  +1.